# Quickest way to declare a field and constructor-inject it

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, resharper

Using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise with Resharper Ultimate.

I find myself often needing to declare a new field, and then have it assigned by a constructor argument. As far as I know, the quickest way is to:

1. Navigate up to the top of the file where the field declarations are
2. Declare the field:

   `private readonly NameOfType _nameOfInstance;`
3. alt-enter on the field name, "Initialize field from constructor"
4. navigate back to where I needed the object and continue

This isn't too onerous, I just find that I do it so many times a day, I'm left wondering whether there's a faster way. Is there a Resharper / VS function / plugin where I can press a key, specify a type, and have it do all of those steps for me? The _nameOfInstance is nearly always just _nameOfType, and it's always private readonly and constructor-injected, so it would be good to reduce this bit of busy-work from my day.

Answer (score 3):

With ReSharper, you can place the cursor in (or highlight) the parameter in the constructor and use CTRL+R, CTRL+F to create a field from it.

[image: Before]

[image: ReSharper]

[image: After]

Comment: Yep but I don't want to add the parameter to the constructor myself. 
I want to be coding along in a method, decide I need an object, hit the magic key, type in the object type, and have the field declared & constructor-injected for me, leaving me with the field reference.

Comment: Ahh, I don't think that exists in VS or ReSharper. Maybe another extension like Productivity Power Tools has it.

Answer (score 1):

You can type an unused symbol name in your code and hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on it to automatically create a field (or even better, type the new field name, followed by `.field`, which will act like a template/snippet and automatically create a field with that name at the top of the class). You can then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on the new field and select "initialise from constructor" to wire it up in the constructor. This will move you out of the current method, though. ReSharper doesn't offer a way around that, but you can use the "Navigate back" command (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Minus</kbd>) to jump back to the method you were working on.